# Give one preprocessing method that allows you to look in either direction in O(logn)

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a dictionary that takes words from AA to BB. The words are sorted in alphabetical order by AA (that is, all words are sorted in AA, and their corresponding words in BB are right by them). Is it possible to devise methods find_BB() and find_AA() that take a word in AA and BB, respectively, and return the corresponding word in BB and AA, respectively, that run in O(logn) time?

I know this is at least possible for find_BB() if the words are sorted by AA, because then we could just use binary search to find the corresponding BB (and we know this runs in O(logn) time). However, I can't seem to think of a way to arrange the dictionary that allows O(logn) lookup for both find_BB and find_AA. Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. What do you mean by "a dictionary that takes words from AA to BB" What are AA and BB? Words? Sets of words? My best guess is that you want to index pairs of words by both tuples. In that case you can just add redundancy. Copy the array and sort one of the copies by AA and the other by BB

Comment: @NiklasB. That's what he means exactly, he has a sort of a hashmap indexing words in set BB by words in set AA. If AA and BB are disjoint, why not just store a union of both dictionaries. If they are not, just store two dictionaries for mappings to both ways.

Comment: @AshuPachauri How can you know this is what was meant?

Comment: @NiklasB. No one can :) It's just that from what he wrote, it was pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if you can have a map that allows forwards and backwards lookups. This can be done by keeping two maps: one from AA to BB, and the other from BB to AA. If you use a sorted list to implement the map then your lookups are both O(log n), or if you use two hash-tables, both lookups are O(1).

Comment: I can't help but mention that hashtable is not the most efficient data structure for Map with String keys. Searching in hash table has amortized cost of O(1). Not taking into account non-constant cost of String comparison. There are structures designed for this particular task — [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and other radix tees.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd like to mention is that performing the binary search in the sorted array of strings will take more than O(log n), because string comparison itself isn't constant.

Second, you haven't posted any limitations on memory usage. Strictly speaking, having two sorted arrays, one for AA->BB, one for BB->AA will solve your task. You can encapsulate these two arrays in one data structure if you want.

And the last. Have you considered more efficient data structures, such as [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)? You can construct single trie for elements from both AA and BB, for each leaf you store up to two values. If the leaf is the key from AA, you store corresponding BB value (with the marker that this is BB) and vice versa.